# Redis session map does not allow indexing

Tags: session, go, struct, redis, hashmap

I have a web app which uses a session struct with a composed model struct.

```
type Session struct {
    SessionModel
}
type SessionModel interface { }
```

UserSession is the session model composed within `Session`

```
type UserSession struct {
    Name string
    Email string
    Password string
}
```

When I unmarshal JSON session data from Redis, a map is stored in the SessionModel field (the interface which allows classes to embed).

```
func(r SessionStore) Get(s Session, id string) (Session, error){
    bson, err := r.Client.Get(id).Bytes()
    if err != nil {
        return s, err
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bson, &s); err != nil {
        return s, err
    }
    return s, nil
}
```

I can access SessionModel and its type is a map, but when I try to access indexed values, I get the error `invalid operation: session.SessionModel["Username"] (type sessions.SessionModel does not support indexing)`. What is going on?

```
reflect.TypeOf(sessions.SessionModel) //map[string]interface {}
session, err := SessionInstance.Get(sessions.Session{sessions.UserSession{}}, cookie.Value)
username := sessions.SessionModel["Username"] //invalid operation: session.SessionModel["Username"] (type sessions.SessionModel does not support indexing)
```

Comment: have you tried having the `r SessionStore` be a pointer? `r *SessionStore`?

Comment: I did, and that did not do anything.

Comment: ` SessionModel and its type is a map` . Nop. SessionModel is type of `interface{}`, containing a map, in your current example, not systematically. Thus you must perform a type assertion at first before trying to use it as a map.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Also, I said SessionModel was a map because that's what session.SessionModel is according to the reflect.TypeOf function.